# Test for subset of coefficients being zero in R

Tags: r, linear-regression

Suppose I have a linear model

Y=β0+β1X1+β2X2+β3X3+β4X4

I can run the code below in R to create the model and summarize it:

```
model1 <- lm(formula = Y ~ X1+X2+X3+X4, data = df)
summary(model1)
```

The output (among other things) gives a F-statistic which provides information about the hypothesis H0:β1=β2=β3=β4=0.

I want to know if there is a way to test the hypothesis H0:β1=β2=β4=0.

Or, H0:β1=β2=β3

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine that your formula is a formula with removed or unknown X5 and X6. Realizing this approach, the second hypothesis may be checked by removing X3 from the formula and the third hypothesis by removing X4.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I want to know if there is a way (e.g. a function like linearHypothesis() from car package) to do it without changing the model or formula.

Answer (score 0):

First case: H0:β1=β2=β4=0

You would compare two models: one with the  three coefficients in question in a model (which you already have in your workspace), and the otehr without them. The `anova` function will provide an F-statistic for that hypothesis (under the usual assumptions.)

```
  model2 <- lm(formula = Y ~ X3, data = df)
  anova(model1, model2)
```

Second case: H0:β1=β2=β3 I'm suspicious that you forgot to put the `=0` in that compound hypothesis and if so it would simply be

```
  model3 <- lm(formula = Y ~ X4, data = df)
  anova(model1, model3)
```

If it was not that question but rather the joint equality of the three coefficients at an unspecified value, then I don't have an answer. Since it's then a multi-part question on different topics (which are off-topic on SO) and since testing for the joint equality of three non-zero coefficients is a rather different statistical question, you should first be getting advice at `CrossValidated.com`.